# How can we temporary off the running website & gives a message "This site is Temprorary unavailable"

Tags: asp.net

How can we temporary off the running website & gives a message "This site is Temprorary unavailable", actully i want to gives a power to admin he can temporary on/Off the website... according to my need i dnt want to add web_offline.htm page. I simply do it by button control i.e. Active website & Deactive website(dynamic method)

Comment: You'll still need an offline.htm but you can use the scripting and database to deliver the script dynamically.

Comment: Thanks Marshall for your reply, i have tried so many method from last 3 days but i doesnt solve this issue. Can you write a code or describe in brief.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to do this per your requirements would be to create an **app_offline.html**, and connect a simple rename method to your admin on/off button.  When the admin clicks *On*, rename the file to **app_offline_.html**, or whatever, and vice versa.  That would be a simple implementation, and you could given the IIS worker process access to that one file for security reasons.

Comment: Thanks dbaseman, I'll try this method, & if you get another way please write here..